# php - if string contains only '\n'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set empty MySQL fields to NULL if all they contain is a line break.

```
if ($field === '\n') :
  $sql = "UPDATE table SET field = NULL
  WHERE id = '$id'
  ";
endif;
```

For some reason, it does not work. I did check the field, it only contains just one linebreak.

What could be a problem?

Comment: Maybe it's treating the '\n' as a string literal instead of a line break.

Comment: Because linebreak is `"\n"`

Comment: `'\n'` is a backslash followed by an `n`, `"\n"` is a line break. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes inhibit escape sequence replacement. Try `"\n"`:

```php
if ($field === "\n") {
  $sql = "UPDATE table SET field = NULL
  WHERE id = '$id'
  ";
}
```

Comment: Yup. It worked, thank you!